# Remove development mode from eclipse gwt project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have to deploy a gwt project in a remote server. I have developed it in Eclipse in my local machine and debugged it in dev mode and it is working fine.

But in order to deploy it in external server it should not be in dev mode. I have to copy only the compiled version. So I did a clean and built the project and transferred my war file to the external server. But the server shows the error could not run in super dev mode.

I deleted the project and built in newly and transferred the war file and  without running it. Still the same error occurs. Is there a way to check if dev mode is removed from the contents of the war file?

Answer (score 1):

open the project Properties ->Google ->Web Toolkit the uncheck use GWT option and this will disable the development mode. =)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete project :)  Simply stop the development mode - click on Development Mode tab and then "Terminate selected launch" (red square button). After that you can re-compile and deploy your project.

Comment: I did it. But there is no change.

Comment: Then restart Eclipse. Something went wrong. Typically, if you stop the dev mode, you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Now the project loads in the remote server but it does not work completely. I get the first(login) screen and after I click login, no action is performed. But it works fine in my local machine.   I did the following steps after stopping the dev mode.   1.Clean  2.Build  3.Google->GWT compile 4. Copy the contents of war to remote server.

Comment: The problem you describe is not related to the dev mode. Check what exceptions you see in a browser when you run your code on a remote server.

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ../class... Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class xxxServiceImpl.java)..  As far as I new, there is no mistake in the server class.

Comment: I found that this exception occurs when compiler version is later than that of exection. I have used the latest jdk version in my local machine but I can't change the jre  in remote server.

Comment: Most probably the jre version of remote server is also 1.8. Unable to identify the issue

Comment: This exception always indicates different Java versions. Check Eclipse  or Maven settings for your project (Java facet or pom.xml).